# Android layer that helps user

Tags: android

I'm making an app and I'd like to help the user the first time he uses my app. I know that some others help the user with a layer that tells him what to do with a transparent background. And...I'd like to do this but I can't find any way.

Someone see what I'm talking about?

Comment: @Thomas: I didn't vote, but in 4 lines of text, there's at least 5 spelling errors. If you read it, the question is 'Someone see what im talking about huh?' (not useful/not a real question). There's some side talk that could be interpreted as a question, but isn't phrased as such (unclear). It's unclear if the OP is looking for code, a pointer towards some element of the API, or techniques that can be used to achieve his goal.  It's also unclear what the goal is, does a transparent layer allow click through?  It seems like there are multiple reasons why one might decide to down vote.

Comment: Dude, im french, im doing my best. i was asking for any help. code if you have code, an url if you have one to give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are of course several different ways of doing this, the simplest is probably displaying a Dialog, and changing the layout of the Dialog to match what you want to help the user with.

```
// Create a new Dialog
    dialog = new Dialog(this);

// Set the content of the dialog
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_help_layout);

// Define the button            
    Button close_button = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.your_close_button);

// Set onClickslistener
    close_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();           
        }
    });

// Show the dialog 
dialog.show();
```

in the XML you can set the background to:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

If you have a TextView or ImageView inside of your xml for the dialog, you can simply just change the helping text/image by defining it the same wat as with the button and changing it when appropriate.

Comment: For a more interactive way you can also place your whole layout in a relativeLayout, then place helping layouts "on top" of you other layout and show/hide them with setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with showing recently prepared pictures in fullscreen?

Make screenshots of your app, draw some comments, arrows, etc, and create the image slider!

Comment: Well showing pictures is cleary ugly. There's no way to do it without a big pic ?